# Generating XHTML from Servlet after XSL Transformation

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformation

I've written a servlet that takes some xml and xsl and produces a PDF, using ITextRenderer, and displays it on the screen.

However, what I wish to do now is to display the resulting XHTML from the transformation on a webpage. I've created a new servlet which gets the xml and xsl as normal, but I'm unsure how to get the resultant XHTML string.

I've had a look online and tried using the javax.xml.transform.Transformer to create a DOMResult object, but I don't know how to pull out the html from this object (presuming it's there at all).

Can anyone provide me with a little help on this please?

Thanks in advance,

-gearoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is [Xalan](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/)